# Datediff not working on VBA query to access in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access, datediff

I am trying to make this basic select query on vba in excel:

```
"SELECT * FROM Tabela1 WHERE DateDiff('yyyy', [Vencimento], " & filter & ") = 0"
```

So I want take all results where the year on "Vencimento" match the desired year. But this Datediff returns -111 (or something like this) when "filter = 2016" and "Vencimento = 01/11/2016".

[Vencimento] is a column on a access table, and filter is in a cell on excel. I guess excel are not working with [Vencimento] as a date even I configuring in access this column as date and I have no idea how make this.

Comment: Access <> Excel - what platform are you working on?

Comment: *[Vencimento] is a column in a table* - if it's one field in a column you need to place the table name in front ... better yet, get the value loaded into a variable (however you get it) and use that variable in the formula.

Comment: You are comparing a _date value_ with a _year_. That will not work.

Comment: I am using access to store the data and excel to "display" the data, actually I tried with a date and a year, but the problem is the access, when I use two excel variable it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work in T-SQL and MS Access:

```
SELECT * FROM Tabela1 WHERE YEAR( [Vencimento] ) = 2016
```

So if you're looking to build that from the value held in a cell called ***filter*** then:

```
SQL$ = "SELECT * FROM Tabela1 WHERE YEAR( [Vencimento] ) = " & range("filter").value
```

But if your ***filter*** cell contains a date, but is formatted to only show the year then you'll need to extract the Year value from that like so:

```
SQL$ = "SELECT * FROM Tabela1 WHERE YEAR( [Vencimento] ) = " & Year(range("filter").value)
```